# How can I override all base virtual functions in NetBeans?

Tags: c++, netbeans, overriding, netbeans-8

I need to override all `virtual` functions from base class. How can I do it in [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans)?

Comment: I know only how to do this one-by-one: In your inheriting class use *Complete Code* (Source -> Complete Code or Ctrl + Space) and select those marked with *override*.